# declaring a variable in php oop methods

Tags: php, oop, variables, methods

What does $iteration_method = 'get_file_object' means here. Is this same as declaring a variable and assign it a string value here? or does it have some other meaning? or does it has some other meaning?

```
protected function get_file_objects($iteration_method = 'get_file_object') {
        $upload_dir = $this->get_upload_path();
        if (!is_dir($upload_dir)) {
            return array();
        }
        return array_values(array_filter(array_map(
            array($this, $iteration_method),
            scandir($upload_dir)
        )));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That`s mean if your dont pass any argument to method the variable inside method will have value  'get_file_object', in other case get value of passed varaible, for example;

```
 class test{
    public function test($test = 'hello world'){
        echo $test;
    }
 }

 $a = new test();
 $a->test(); // output hello world
 $a->test('im Michael'); // output im Michael
```

Comment: Thanks @Ziupex - that's what I wanted to know